# "Use pattern matching" Message

Tags: visual-studio, design-patterns, pattern-matching, message

Visual Studio gives me the Message:

> Use pattern matching

With the Code IDE0020

The Snippet:

```
private void BTclear_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Button BTclear = (Button)sender;
  if (BTclear.DataContext is ObservableCollectionUser)
  {
    ObservableCollectionUser clearMe = (ObservableCollectionUser)BTclear.DataContext;
    Users.Remove(clearMe);
  }
}
```

The if statement is green underlined.

What does it mean and how can I optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type pattern to introduce a new variable of type `ObservableCollectionUser` without that cast:

```cs
private void BTclear_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button) sender;
    if (button.DataContext is ObservableCollectionUser user)
    {
        Users.Remove(user);
    }
}
```

(I renamed `BTclear` to `button` to be more idiomatic in terms of naming conventions, but the important part is the introduction of the `user` variable in the `is` expression.)

Note that this isn't really about optimization - it's about the code being clearer and simpler. It *may* be slightly faster, but it's very unlikely to be significant.